# List<T> where T: enum

Tags: c#, enums

I would like to create a list of enums, like I can create  a list of types of enums,

e.g.

```
public enum Enum1{
    Member1,
    Member2,
    Member3
}

public enum Enum2 {
    Member1,
    Member2,
    Member3
}

public List<Type> EnumTypes = new List<Type> { 
    typeof(Enum1),
    typeof(Enum2),
}
```

works fine, but

```
public List<System.Enum> EnumTypes = new List<System.Enum> { 
    Enum1,
    Enum2
};
```

does not work.

I would like to add the following details: 
The first part of my code works, it is running all the time...
the second part does not work, and I mentioned it.
I want to add some more details to the underlying problem:

I am in a situation where I have a list of Types of enumerations (i.e. EnumTypes ). I iterate through the list do to something. Unfortunately I need to extend the body and call Enumhelper.GetEnumNames, where T axtually is an enum. I work with WEC7, where Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)) does not exist. 
So I hoped there is a way to build a list of Enumerations, instead of enumtypes, and iterate over that list. 
Also if there is a way, if I have a Type, typeof(T), where T is an enum, to call 
Enumhelper.GetEnumNames, so to say get an enumeration from its type, that would help a lot.

```
public void enumtester(){
    foreach (var typeOfEnum in EnumHelper.EnumTypes) {
        ........
        // typeOfEnum is typeof(T), but I do not know how to call the following method
         List<string> names = EnumHelper.GetEnumNames<T>();
}
```

Comment: Correct. What was the question?

Comment: @João `I would like to` kinda implies the question `how do I?`

Comment: @Rawling It does, but I can't gather from his code snippets exactly what it is he would like to do. Not only does his code not work, it also doesn't mean anything...

Comment: I was you afraid you would say that. Actually I got stuck in a situation where I have a list of EnumTypes (as defined), but I want to call a method, that requires the enumeration as Parameter, signature is  public List<string> GetEnumNames<T>(). T is an Enum, not typeof(enum) and I work with WEC7, where enum.getvalues and enum.getnames is not defined

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a list of enums, like I can create a list of types of enums

You can't. And your code doesn't make sense, your example would be treating it as a variable of Type `Enum` in adding it to the list, it would need to be: `EnumTypes.Add(Enum1.Member1);` etc..

It's similar to doing this:

```
List<MyObject> foo = new List<MyObject>();
foo.Add(MyObject);
```

Obviously won't work.

Why not do something like this instead:

```
public static class EnumTypes
{
    public enum Enum1
    {
        Member1,
        Member2,
        Member3
    }

    public enum Enum2
    {
        Member1,
        Member2,
        Member3
    }
}
```

Then you can access enum members like this:

```
EnumTypes.Enum1.Member1
```

Etc..

That way you don't even need a list containing all of the enums and when you come to add a new enum to the class, you don't have to update the list initialization.

Comment: Thank you for yor answer. Unfortunately I believe I need the list, because I iterate over it, to call a method for very enumeration, like I added in my questions

Comment: Then instead of doing: `EnumTypes.Add(Enum1)` you would need to manually add each enum member e.g. `EnumTypes.Add(Enum1.Member1);` etc..